# `IS NOT NULL` has very large performance penalty compared to `> 0` on `INT` field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very odd issue where a query slows down to a crawl if I test an `INT` field for `NULL` values.

The query is this:

```
WITH CommonRows (Dm2Id) AS (
    SELECT LibraryId
      FROM dbo.Items AS i1
      JOIN Test.Items AS i2
        ON i1.Dm2Id = i2.Dm2Id
     WHERE HasNew = 1
       AND HasOld = 1
       -- Note this: odd things happening here
       AND LibraryId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT COALESCE(New.ImageLibraryId, Old.ImageLibraryId) AS ImageLibraryId,
        COALESCE(New.Field, Old.Field) AS Field,
        New.Value AS New,
        Old.Value AS Old
   FROM (SELECT ImageLibraryId,
                LEFT(CAST(TitleItemId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TitleItemId,
                LEFT(CAST(Title AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Title,
                LEFT(CAST(Author AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Author,
                LEFT(CAST(AuthorFirstname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS AuthorFirstname,
                LEFT(CAST(AuthorLastname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS AuthorLastname,
                LEFT(CAST(Teaser AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Teaser,
                LEFT(CAST(TeaserListView AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TeaserListView,
                LEFT(CAST(Language AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Language,
                LEFT(CAST(PubYear AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS PubYear,
                LEFT(CAST(FictionNonFiction AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS FictionNonFiction,
                LEFT(CAST(TargetAudience AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TargetAudience,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesTitle AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesTitle,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesSeqNo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesSeqNo,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesTotalCnt AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesTotalCnt
           FROM dbo.TitleItems
          WHERE ImageLibraryId IN (SELECT * FROM CommonRows)) p
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Field IN
            (TitleItemId, Title, Author, AuthorFirstname, AuthorLastname, Teaser,
             TeaserListView, Language, PubYear, FictionNonFiction, TargetAudience,
             SeriesTitle, SeriesSeqNo, SeriesTotalCnt)) AS New
   FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT ImageLibraryId,
                LEFT(CAST(TitleItemId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TitleItemId,
                LEFT(CAST(Title AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Title,
                LEFT(CAST(Author AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Author,
                LEFT(CAST(AuthorFirstname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS AuthorFirstname,
                LEFT(CAST(AuthorLastname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS AuthorLastname,
                LEFT(CAST(Teaser AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Teaser,
                LEFT(CAST(TeaserListView AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TeaserListView,
                LEFT(CAST(Language AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Language,
                LEFT(CAST(PubYear AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS PubYear,
                LEFT(CAST(FictionNonFiction AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS FictionNonFiction,
                LEFT(CAST(TargetAudience AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS TargetAudience,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesTitle AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesTitle,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesSeqNo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesSeqNo,
                LEFT(CAST(SeriesTotalCnt AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SeriesTotalCnt
           FROM CatalogSearch.dbo.TitleItems
          WHERE ImageLibraryId IN (SELECT * FROM CommonRows)) p
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Field IN
            (TitleItemId, Title, Author, AuthorFirstname, AuthorLastname, Teaser,
             TeaserListView, Language, PubYear, FictionNonFiction, TargetAudience,
             SeriesTitle, SeriesSeqNo, SeriesTotalCnt)) AS Old
     ON (New.ImageLibraryId = Old.ImageLibraryId AND New.Field = Old.Field COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
  WHERE (New.Value <> Old.Value COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
         OR New.Value IS NULL AND Old.Value IS NOT NULL
         OR New.Value IS NOT NULL AND Old.Value IS NULL)
         -- fjernet rækker hvor New.Value indeholder mere information end Old.Value, men Old.Value indgår i starten af New.Value
         AND NOT (New.Field IN ('Teaser', 'TeaserListView') AND New.Value LIKE Old.Value + '%')
         -- fjernet række fordi den har fået et ekstra space med i Old.Value i midten af teksten
         AND NOT (New.Field IN ('Teaser', 'TeaserListView') AND New.ImageLibraryId = 800314)
         -- fjernet række fordi den tolkes som ukendt i New.Value (pga. fejldata i Bibkat) og som dansk i Old.Value
         AND NOT (New.Field = 'Language' AND New.ImageLibraryId = 800252)
        -- This is being tested separately in TitleItemGroups
        AND NOT New.Field = 'TitleItemId'
```

If I run it as written above, the query will run for several minutes before it starts returning just a few rows at a time. I haven't had the patience to wait for the query to finish - I suspect it'll run for 10+ minutes before finishing.

*But* if I replace `AND LibraryId IS NOT NULL` with `AND LibraryId > 0` (which in this case will give the exact same result - I have checked this), the query runs in 30 seconds.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the explain plan.

SQL-server perform a full scan of the table if you use a `IS [NOT] NULL` operator on a column.
If you use an index on a NULLABLE column, it will not be used.

You can create a composed index, with a not null and a nullable column in order to suprass the problem.

Comment: There is an index on the underlying `LibraryId` and this field does (obviously) allow nulls.So using the criteria `LibraryId > 0` causes the server to use the index in stead of a full table scan?

Comment: Forgot to mention: I haven't had patience to look at the explain plan because it is huge - some of the sources in this query are views themselves.

Comment: -1 This is not true. `IS [NOT] NULL` queries can use an index. See both of these use an index seek  http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bpsg.png

Comment: @mzedeler - Well the answer will be in the execution plan. Maybe different cardinality estimates causing a different plan for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith - thanks for the update. I'll try to decipher and compare the execution plans covering the two cases.